# com.dantsu.escposprinter.exceptions.EscPosConnectionException: Unable to connect to bluetooth device in android version 13

Tags: android, escpos

how to solve this problem?

com.dantsu.escposprinter.exceptions.EscPosConnectionException: Unable to connect to bluetooth device in android version 13

using ESCPOS-thermal_printer library.
how to solve that.
below version 13 is ok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest version of this library, at least [v3.3.0](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/releases) to get it working with [Android 13](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/issues/410).